# I can ping the IP address, but I have no idea what the device is in my network

Tags: ip, ping, ip-address

I can ping the IP address, but I have no idea what the device is in my network. How can I find out what the device is? 
I somehow have the device registered on Spiceworks and it has detected it to be a iLO computer so far.

Comment: An iLo computer is probably an HP server with the network cable plugged into the management port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using NMap with the ZenMap GUI to have it obtain the devices MAC address and guess the manufacturer of the device and operating system based on its fingerprint. The utility can be downloaded here: https://nmap.org/zenmap/

For this to work, I believe that the device must be on the same subnet as your scanning computer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not look on your router to see what devices are attached? Failing that, use advanced IP scanner to scan your subnet/network to also see the devices that are on it.